# Choosing IDE and frameworks for RIA development

Tags: web-applications, ria, rich-internet-application

I'm planning to develop a Rich Internet Application, so I'm searching for choosing IDE and frameworks for a rapid development.

This web application will be a web-based ERP, so I need something that helps me about developing data-entry and data-searching forms, and data-reports.

It should possibly have desktop-like look and feel. The resulting application should be Swing-like.

I'm searching for an IDE which supports:
- Visual UI Design
- Data binding of UI Components
- Event-driven programming

For Java Swing desktop applications I'm using the Netbeans IDE, which supports all above requirements, but unfortunately it does not support them for web development...

I hope you can help me finding the right tools. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What do you think about ZK and GWT?

Comment: I think that I'll use GWT for this, with GWTDesigner, it seems a good choice

Answer (score 0):

FLash builder + eclipse + flex sdk

Comment: Flash Builder will support visual data binding?

Comment: Isn't flex only for client side? It's a front-end technology.. and flash it's not supported on every devices.

Comment: I'm oriented towards java technologies for back-end, and perhaps javascript for front-end.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse IDE and the RAP rich AJAX platform are a good bet for something structured like a ERP app;
http://www.eclipse.org/rap/

Comment: Is there any visual editor for RAP? What do you think about RAP vs GWT?

Comment: I found that using the http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html tools was the easiest for rapid development of the components.